# Is there a better way to write this if-else statement?

Tags: r

I am wondering if there is an easier way to create these variables than what I am doing? I am trying to turn the values of my vehicle type variable in to variables themselves.

```
##Set up boolean values##
norm.knnN$gearbox[norm.knnN$gearbox=="automatic"] = 1
norm.knnN$gearbox[norm.knnN$gearbox=="manual"] = 0
norm.knnN$gearbox = as.numeric(norm.knnN$gearbox)

norm.knnN$bus= ifelse(norm.knnN$vehicleType=="bus",1,0)
norm.knnN$cabrio= ifelse(norm.knnN$vehicleType=="cabrio",1,0)
norm.knnN$coupe= ifelse(norm.knnN$vehicleType=="coupe",1,0)
norm.knnN$limousine= ifelse(norm.knnN$vehicleType=="limousine",1,0)
norm.knnN$otherCar= ifelse(norm.knnN$vehicleType=="other",1,0)
norm.knnN$small_car= ifelse(norm.knnN$vehicleType=="small_car",1,0)
norm.knnN$station_wagon= ifelse(norm.knnN$vehicleType=="station_wagon",1,0)
norm.knnN$suv= ifelse(norm.knnN$vehicleType=="suv",1,0)
norm.knnN$vehicleType = NULL


norm.knnN$cng= ifelse(norm.knnN$fuelType=="cng",1,0)
norm.knnN$diesel= ifelse(norm.knnN$fuelType=="diesel",1,0)
norm.knnN$electric= ifelse(norm.knnN$fuelType=="electric",1,0)
norm.knnN$hybrid= ifelse(norm.knnN$fuelType=="hybrid",1,0)
norm.knnN$lpg= ifelse(norm.knnN$fuelType=="lpg",1,0)
norm.knnN$otherFuel= ifelse(norm.knnN$fuelType=="other",1,0)
norm.knnN$petrol= ifelse(norm.knnN$fuelType=="petrol",1,0)
norm.knnN$fuelType = NULL


norm.knnN$audi= ifelse(norm.knnN$brand=="audi",1,0)
norm.knnN$bmw= ifelse(norm.knnN$brand=="bmw",1,0)
norm.knnN$mercedes_benz= ifelse(norm.knnN$brand=="mercedes_benz",1,0)
norm.knnN$opel= ifelse(norm.knnN$brand=="opel",1,0)
norm.knnN$volkswagen= ifelse(norm.knnN$brand=="volkswagen",1,0)
norm.knnN$brand = NULL


norm.knnN$notRepairedDamage[norm.knnN$notRepairedDamage=="yes"] = 1
norm.knnN$notRepairedDamage[norm.knnN$notRepairedDamage=="no"] = 0
norm.knnN$notRepairedDamage = as.numeric(norm.knnN$notRepairedDamage)
```

Comment: you seem to be dummy coding your variables. There are a few methods to do this, this is one `model.matrix(~ 0 + vehicleType, data=norm.knnN)` etc

Comment: A reproducible example along with expected output to better understand your question would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a helper function in the `cobalt` package for this called `splitfactor()`, which splits factors into dummy variables. You would run the following:

```
norm.knnN <- cobalt::splitfactor(norm.knnN, 
                                c("gearbox", "vehicleType", 
                                 "fuelType", "brand", "notRepairedDamage"), 
                                drop.first = "if2")
```

Setting `drop.first = "if2"` makes it so that if a factor has two values (e.g., `"yes"` and `"no"`), one of the dummy variables will be dropped since it is perfectly redundant to the other one.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is working beautifully in my code and such a good tool for future projects.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use dplyr's syntax. There are some literature to learn how to use the syntax. (https://genomicsclass.github.io/book/pages/dplyr_tutorial.html)

In the syntax, I usually use case_when function to make several condition rather than ifelse function.

```
norm.knnN$gearbox[norm.knnN$gearbox=="automatic"] = 1
norm.knnN$gearbox[norm.knnN$gearbox=="manual"] = 0
```

It would be changed to this syntax I mentioned.

```
 norm.knnN %>%
    mutate(gearbox = case_when(
    gearbox == "automatic" ~ 1,
    gearbox == "manual" ~ 0,
    TRUE ~ NA))
```